# docker run fails to start command specified as CMD option (path, library no found)

Tags: docker

I can start a shell and the target program:

```
docker run -it mycontainer bash
myscript.py
```

However, when I start the program directly, it fails:

```
docker run -it mycontainer myscript.py
```

It does not find the path. When I provide the path (usr/bin/myscript.py), then the program, it does not find the library: (libpython3.4m.so.rh-python34-1.0: cannot open shared object file).

What can be the reason?

Comment: Does your shell load environment from `~/.bash_profile` ? Does that export `PATH`? When you run by itself, is the same `PATH` still defined?

Comment: Please post the `Dockerfile` of `mycontainer` so everyone know how is it built.